# Ionic: Adding Angular-material to Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-material

I am new to Ionic, trying to create a sample app. Here I am trying to use **angular-material**. So, I downloaded angular-material files into **www/lib/angular-material** folder. It is working fine in browser but when I am trying to generate apk BUILD FAILED. Getting this error

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 46.514 secs

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Android\myApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\assets\debug\www\lib\angular-material (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you already tried to run the build-command as admin/root or do your project-dirs have some rw-restrictions?